# Reading a barcode in excel to see if there is a match

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with Excel 2016.  I have a smidgen of experience with VBA for applications, and some experience with programming.

I'm trying to take input from a barcode scanner, compare it to a column in a spreadsheet, and if there's a match, put a few characters and a date stamp in some cells (Initials and date, each in separate columns).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108954/excel-barcode-scanning-macro) has a very similar use-case, and includes a code sample.  I have tried the code sample and can't get it to work.  At first, there was a problem with the array.  Eventually I figured out you could do "C2:C8" and that seemed to work, though that's not documented anywhere (Probably part of a basics course/class, but not findable).  There was an error about sub or function defined for [Match()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A), so I enabled the [Solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915646/excel-vba-compile-error-sub-of-function-not-defined#25986487) Add-in in the [security center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196600.aspx).  That didn't fix it, so I found this [forum post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/397296-compile-error-sub-function-not-defined-3-line-macro.html) that explained Match wasn't a VBA function.

Now, I get an error after clicking the button "Run time error 1004, unable to get Match property of the WorksheetFunction class", clicking debug takes me to the same line.

Here is the code I have wound up with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")
matchedCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(code, Range("C2:C8"), 0)
matchedCell.Offset(0, 2) = Now

End Sub
```

This is incredibly frustrating because I thought this was a simple thing and already solved.  Instead of working to solve the problem and build software, it seems I'm fighting syntax and/or the environment.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Match` returns the row number (when it finds a match), so  you can't set `matchedCell` that I think is a `Range` as the way you did. Are you trying to find in which cell from Range("C2:C8") there is a match with your `InputBox`? and then insert the current time to the cell located 2 columns to the right of that cell ?

Comment: Add "Debug.print code" before the first line beginning "matchedcell=", is the value in your range?  You should also fully qualify a range, ie workbooks("mybook.xlsx").sheets("sheet1").range("C2:C8")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two possibilities:

- use `Match()` function of `Application` object

  and store its returned value in a Variant variable to be checked for any error (if value not found)

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Dim code As Variant
      Dim matchedCell As Variant

      code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")
      matchedCell = Application.Match(code, Range("C2:C8"), 0)
      If Not IsError(matchedCell) Then Range("C2:C8").Cells(matchedCell, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
  End Sub
  ```
- use `Find()` function of `Range` object

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Dim code As Variant
      Dim matchedCell As Range

      code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")
      Set matchedCell = Range("C2:C8").Find(what:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
      If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then matchedCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: beat me to it, fast on the keyboard :)

Comment: @ShaiRado, sometimes (well, too many times) it's the opposite!

Comment: I couldn't get Match() to work, it kept returning Error 2402, which is presumably "#N/A" or not found.  Print statement for code (now renamed to scannedInput) was correct, and matchedCell gave me the error.  I tried changing the variable type of matchedCell to double, but that did not help.  Your second code sample worked immediately without modification, thanks!  That hopefully puts me over the hump and now I can get some work done!

Comment: you are welcome. just to add that both codes worked on the same test data. finally you may  want to mark answer as accepted. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.Match` , and continue running your code only if there is a successful `Match`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim MatchRow As Variant
Dim code As Variant
Dim matchedCell As Range

code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")

' verify that there is a successful match in the searched range
If Not IsError(Application.Match(code, Range("C2:C8"), 0)) Then
    MatchRow = Application.Match(code, Range("C2:C8"), 0) '<-- get the row number 
    Set matchedCell = Range("C" & MatchRow + 1) '<-- set the range (add 1 row since you are starting from row 2)
    matchedCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now

    'option 2: without setting the range
    Range("C" & MatchRow).Offset(1, 2).Value = Now  
End If

End Sub
```